# Pass data through screens in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am new one in React Native. I have to make an app with google map and make possible to change map type from other screen. I am using TabNavigator to switch between screens.

Qestion is how to change map type by switching a radio button in other screen.

This is my HomeScreen map component:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
              mapType={'standard'}
              provider={this.props.provider}
              style={styles.map}
              initialRegion={this.state.region}
              onPress={e => this.onPress(e)}
          >
```

I want to pass a mapType from another screen with radio buttons

```
const MAP_TYPES = {
STANDARD: 'standard',
SATELLITE: 'satellite',
HYBRID: 'hybrid',
TERRAIN: 'terrain',
NONE: 'none',};

var radio_props = [
{label: MAP_TYPES.STANDARD, value: MAP_TYPES.STANDARD },
{label: MAP_TYPES.SATELLITE, value: MAP_TYPES.SATELLITE }];

export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
     static navigationOptions = {
         title: 'Options',
     };

    onPress(value) {
        this.setState({value:value});
        /*
        Here I want to send value to HomeScreen but I don't know how =(
        */
        console.log(value);
    }
 render() {
   return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <RadioForm
         radio_props={radio_props}
         initial={0}
         onPress={(value) => {this.onPress(value)}}
        />
      </ScrollView>
     );
  }
}
```

App Images

[This is my home screen with map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqjbM.jpg)

[This is my switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwgbb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common techniques for this.

1. Use a higher order component to maintain the state of the map type, and pass it down to child components as a prop. Also pass down a function which can be used to update the state in the higher order component.
2. Use a system such as redux to create a single state which you can read and update from anywhere in your application.

It’s a matter of personal preference which method you choose, though if the app is going to get more complex over time, some global state management such as redux may be a good idea to use early on.